# Ajax Load more content

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I want to load some content from 
`/page-0.html?to-page=2` and my current page is 
`/page-0.html?to-page=1.`

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var page = 1;

    $.get('/page-0.html?to-page=' +page, function(html) {
    if(html) {

    $('#result').append(html);
    $('#more').text('Load More Post'); //add text "Load More Post" to button again
        } else {
            $('#more').text('No more Post to load'); // when last record add text "No more posts to load" to button.
        }
    $('#more').click(function() {
    $('#more').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"');
    page += 1;
    });
    }, 'json');

    });
```

html:

```
    <div id="result"></div> <button id="more">Load more</button>
```

If i click load more button it should change the url `/page-0.html?to-page=1 to 2.` Is it possible?

I'm new to jquery. Can someone help me to find my mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var page = 1;
    var getData;
    (getData = function() {
        $.get('/page-0.html?to-page=' +page, function(html) {
            if(html) {

                $('#result').append(html);
                $('#more').text('Load More Post'); //add text "Load More Post" to button again
            } else {
                $('#more').text('No more Post to load'); // when last record add text "No more posts to load" to button.
            }
        }, 'json');
    })();
    $('#more').click(function() {
        $('#more').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"');
        page += 1;
        getData();
    });
});
```

I have used getData function as an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) so that request is automatically hit for the first time and then called the same function later on clicking more.
HTH

Comment: Thanks but its not working  https://codepen.io/alx-ashique/pen/yxaoYa

Comment: Its because you have not added JQuery library  
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at pen.js:9

Comment: check this out https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/3u582twx/ . You will need to check console or network

Comment: I've added https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js but still the page not loading 

Comment: Open the chrome tool, notice the request is being hit but got blocked.

Comment: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/alx-ashique/pen/yxaoYa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://darkweb.wapkiz.mobi/page-0.html?to-page=3'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
w.(anonymous function) @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
getData @ pen.js:6
(anonymous) @ pen.js:19
dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2

Comment: If you are not aware of the chrome dev tools, refer https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/. It will help.

Comment: I'm new to jquery and all that. I've tried a lot but failed. So, can you give me a working script that can do the work without any problem. I know i'm disturbing you but please its a request. 

Comment: Have you tested the code on your project? The code seems to be working, it's just due to security constraints Codepen, Jsfiddle doesn't allow non-https requests to hit. I think the code should work fine on your site. Improved code  https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/3u582twx/16/

Comment: I've tested your codes still not working http://darkweb.wapkiz.mobi/page-12.html

Comment: I've found another code which is working a little bit but whenever i hit the load more button its showing me the same page instead of changing the page number. 

        `function loadMore() {
        $("#loading").html('Loading...').show();
var currPage = 1;

        $.get('page-0.html?to-page?=' + currPage, function(html) {
        $("#results").append(html);
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
}

        $(document).ready(function() {
    var currPage = 1; 
        $("a.next").click(function() {
currPage +=1;
        loadMore();
    });
});`

Comment: 'var currPage = 1;function loadMore() { $("#loading").html('Loading...').show();  $.get('page-0.html?to-page?=' + currPage, function(html) { $("#results").append(html); $("#loading").hide(); }); } $(document).ready(function() { $("a.next").click(function() { currPage +=1; loadMore(); }); });'

Comment: Try moving currPage to global scope